# Invalid redirect URI for Deezer oAuth

Tags: oauth, deezer

Every attempt I make to authenticate at Deezer is answered with the error message:

> You must enter a valid redirect URI

The redirect URI set in my application settings is https://example.com/callback/deezer and the request I make looks something like:

> https://connect.deezer.com/oauth/auth.php?app_id=xxxxxx&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Fcallback%2Fdeezer&scope=basic_access%2Cemail&state=xxxxxx&response_type=code

The app_id value is correct. Any help?

Comment: is the domain declared in your app settings  the same than your redirect_uri?

Comment: @Fred_Dzr yes - is that ok?

Comment: yes, it should be fine normally. What is your app_id please?

Comment: Can you try to set your application domain without the http:// please? You just have to set it without the protocol, we just need the domain

Comment: @Fred_Dzr - seems that you work for Deezer - it will be a good idea to add some kind of validation on application domain field. It's really annoying when you add domain with protocol and it's not working.

Comment: We will implement that in order to help our users, you're right

Answer (score 1):

you must set the "Application domain" as the url which the login script in connection from.

for example, if you're working on your localhost on this url: `http://localhost:3000/index.html`

just put the value `localhost/index.html`, without the port.